# Converting a python 3 dictionary into a dataframe (keys are tuples)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary that has the following structure:

```
Dict [(t1,d1)] = x
```

(x are integers, t1 and d1 are strings)

I want to convert this Dictionary into a dataframe of the following format:

```
   d1 d2 d3 d4
t1  x y  z  x
t2  etc.
t3
t4
...
```

The following command

d.DataFrame([[key,value] for key,value in Dict.items()],columns=["key_col","val_col"])

gives me

key_col  val_col

0  (book, d1)      100

1   (pen, d1)       10

2  (book, d2)       30

3   (pen, d2)        0

How do I make d's my column names and t's my row names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas automatically assumes tuple keys are multiindex. Pass dictionary to series constructor and unstack.

```
pd.Series(dct).unstack()
```